# set parameters for SOAP in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am realy new whis SOAP, so please help me to set parameters for sending a request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ManagedSoapHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <_SID>string</_SID>
    </ManagedSoapHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSessionParameters xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

this is my code

```
   $client->getInfo(array("Header" => array("ManagedSoapHeader" => array("_SID" => $sessionID)))); //->ManagedSoapHeader(array("_SID" => $sessionID));
```

But I getting an fatal error about setting a class on server... no idea about this... so my question:

How to set _SID?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what library you are using but you may be interested in reading the SOAP Client that is already included with PHP 5.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

For instance, to set the parameters for SOAP using the PHP SoapClient you would simply need to do this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('proxy_host'     => "localhost",
                                            'proxy_port'     => 8080,
                                            'proxy_login'    => "some_name",
                                            'proxy_password' => "some_password"));
```

You may also want to research other third party clients such as NuSOAP which is meant to be an improvement on the native PHP client.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Comment: yes I do use the php "native" client, and for other request it works fine, this is where I get the session ID, but for my next Request I need to send the session ID...

Comment: I get this error: Object reference not set to an object instance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php Something like

```
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
$client->getInfo(...)
```

Finally, why do you call `$client->getInfo(...)`? In the SOAP Body I see you have just `GetSessionParameters` operation. IMHO you should call

```
$client->GetSessionParameters(...)
```